# Transferring data from onReceive to SQL database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an `SQL` database that works, and the `broadcast receiver` that functions, but I can't seem to get the info out of the database, into global variables (`latInfo`, `LonInfo`) so I can use them to enter data into the database. The `BroadcastReceiver`gets it's information from a service that gets `LocationManager` gps coordinate and the `location_text` is a `textview` that is updated every time a new set of coordinates is set.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(br == null){
            br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent z) {
                    //location_text.append("\n" + z.getExtras().get("coordinates"));
                    latInfo = (double) z.getExtras().get("latitude");
                    lonInfo = (double) z.getExtras().get("longitude");
                    String x = "Latitude: " + latInfo + ", Longitude: " + lonInfo + "\n";
                    location_text.append(x);

                }

            };

        }

        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }
```

This is the method I want to implement to add data to the database
simply put, once the data I can get into the global variables (`lonInfo`, `latInfo`) is registered by the class below, it calls another class to get the cell signal `cdmaSignal` and all three get inserted into the database.

```
public void infoCollection(){
        if(lonInfo != 0 && latInfo != 0){
            cdmaInfo = sl.cdmaSignal;

            SQLInfoDatabase sid = new SQLInfoDatabase(cdmaInfo,lonInfo,latInfo);

            cdmaSignal.setText(cdmaInfo);

            dbh.addInfo(sid);
        }
    }
```

How do I get the received data from the `onReceive` method to stay as global variables between updates of the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make static variables or can use singleton class

below is sample of singleton class

```
public class SharedClass
{
    private static SharedClass sharedClass;

    // global variables
    public double latInfo, LonInfo;

    public static SharedClass getInstance()
    {
        if (sharedClass == null)
            sharedClass = new SharedClass();

        return sharedClass;
    }

    private SharedClass()
    {
    }
}
```

you can access latInfo or LonInfo from anywhere in application by doing this

```
SharedClass.getInstance().latInfo
SharedClass.getInstance().LonInfo
```

Comment: you got any other choices?

Comment: singleton class is good option..what's the problem with that?

Comment: Mostly because I never used it before. I have no issue with it, but I was hoping for a more straight forward solution. Like a line of code to keep the getExtras from nulling. to  I'm pretty new to programming so I'd have to research it for a while.